# Diff multiple versions of a project

Tags: diff

I've recently started a new job where I have taken over developing an existing system. The system (PHP site if it matters) was setup with three instances.

- Live site (Used by staff and customers)
- Test site (Mainly used to demonstrate feature requests to staff)
- Dev site (Used by the previous developer)

This seemed like a reasonable thing to do (They didn't have a SVN server setup). But now that I'm a couple weeks in, I've noticed that the code (and database schemas) is different across all three sites. I expected there to be differences between dev and live, but live has features that dev doesn't.

I've run [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/) and I am looking at around 180 modified files and 110 new files between the different versions. Is there any software or easier method to compare the code across all the versions than just performing diffs file by file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`meld`](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGcQFjAA&url=http://meldmerge.org/&ei=HpEkUJrqGauTiQfS_YDwBw&usg=AFQjCNGxYTH5-hiiYkrAouLnanmiJOthZA) is excellent for comparing entire folders (and files) recursively in a drill-down style.

Comment: Do you know how well the Windows version works? I could take the code home and use the Linux version on my computer if the Windows one is a bit flakey.

Comment: Based on my last install on Windows (more than a year ago), the Windows version works just fine, however has problems remembering recent files. I had worked around this with some batch files/wrappers, but the latest version might have fixed these issues. You also need to install the GTK runtime if not already there.

Comment: Seems to be working well on Windows. It even has three way comparison which I wasn't expecting :D

Comment: @Dracs even as a file-level diff/merge tool it is top of the line; it has quite a fanbase :)

Comment: Not a bad program overall, had a couple of crashes. But didn't lose anything from them. Only took me around 4 hours to finish it all up. Now to get some proper version control setup.

Answer (score 1):

Blatant plug: If you're interested in diffing *all three* sites against each other (as opposed to diffing them two at a time), you might be interested in [my `difdef` utility](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/difdef). It can produce a merge of N directories à la `diff -r -D` but unlike traditional `diff` it works for N>2 as well as N=2. (And unlike `diff3` it does not assume any specific genealogical relationship among the versions.)

E.g. you could do

```
difdef -r -DSITE={LIVE,TEST,DEV} {live,test,dev} -o merged
grep -lr 'SITE==' merged | xargs $EDITOR
```

to open up an editor window on every file that differs between any two versions.

`difdef` does *not* have a better UI than the traditional `diff` utility, but it *does* have this nifty ability to diff more than 2 versions simultaneously. Open-source, C++, MIT license.